# Template for Generalized Hough Transform OpenCV Python

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I'm rather confused how to use a generalized Hough transform with openCV Python. When I set a template with a ROI of grayscale image, it shows this error:

```sh
Incorrect type of self (must be 'GeneralizedHough' or its derivative)
```

Here is my example code:

```py
alg = cv.GeneralizedHoughGuil()
# Simple create template with 1 channel black images with size 5x5
template = np.zeros((5,5))
alg.setTemplate(template)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know the only way out in this situation is to rebuild OpenCV with CV_EXPORTS_W and CV_WRAP directives. 
[answers.opencv topic](http://answers.opencv.org/question/211122/how-to-use-opencv-generalizedhoughtransform-class-with-python/)

Answer (score 4):

Call `cv.createGeneralizedHoughGuil` instead of `cv.GeneralizedHoughGuil`:

```
alg = cv.createGeneralizedHoughGuil()
template = np.zeros((5,5))
alg.setTemplate(template)
```